# Making two series point in opposite directions in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a column chart with two series, one of which I want to go down and the other up, like this:
[image]

However both of the series have positive y-values, which I can't change, e.g.

```
blue = [1746181, 1884428, 2089758, 2222362, 2537431, 2507081, 2443179,
                2664537, 3556505, 3680231, 3143062, 2721122, 2229181, 2227768,
                2176300, 1329968, 836804, 354784, 90569, 28367, 3878];
grey = [1656154, 1787564, 1981671, 2108575, 2403438, 2366003, 2301402, 2519874,
                3360596, 3493473, 3050775, 2759560, 2304444, 2426504, 2568938, 1785638,
                1447162, 1005011, 330870, 130632, 21208];
```

Using highcharts options, is it possible to have a chart like this? The example I used for the screenshot is [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zares7x9/) if it's useful to anyone, however it has a series with negative values which is not an option for me. Instead [my data is more like this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zares7x9/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to use two separate yAxes: http://jsfiddle.net/zares7x9/2/, where one of them is `reversed`:

```
        yAxis: [{
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            top: '5%',
            height: '45%',
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return (Math.abs(this.value) / 1000000) + 'M';
                }
            },
            min: 0,
            max: 4000000
        }, {
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return (Math.abs(this.value) / 1000000) + 'M';
                }
            },
            offset: 0,
            showFirstLabel: false, // hide 0-value
            reversed: true, //reverse
            top: '50%',
            height: '45%',
            min: 0,
            max: 4000000
        }],
```

Setting `top` and `height` allows you to render axes like one. Note, that you need to set for one of the series `yAxis: 1`, to inform Highcharts which series belongs to which axis.

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly what I was after. I'd tried using `reversed` but I just got [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7pqc95t5/). Looks like `top` and `height` were what I needed to use.